# What's the difference between maven webapp and maven site archetype?

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

Documentation says that

**maven-archetype-webapp** type is:

> A simple Java web application

**maven-archetype-site** type is:

> A more complex site project

**maven-archetype-site-simple** type is:

> A simple site generation project

These descriptions do not make it any cleaner for me, so what's the real difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **maven-archetype-webapp** will create a webapp that will generated a WAR file to running inside webserver (i.e. Tomcat)

**maven-archetype-site**  and **maven-archetype-site-simple** is varying degree of complexity of project website.

Also, here is a article that explains sites.
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071733/java-app-dev/get-the-most-out-of-maven-2-site-generation.html